# Xamarin iOS binding library with multiple frameworks (native references) not working

Tags: objective-c, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.ios-binding

I have 1 framework which is dependent on 2 other frameworks. For this, I created one binding library for iOS and included all three frameworks in it.

After creating this binding project, I included (added as reference project) it to a native iOS app. Now, the project(native) compiles without any error but the app doesn't run on the simulator. If I comment out the SDK code then app works perfectly. Not able to proceed further, what am I missing?

**Update**:

After below comments I checked frameworks again (just to be sure that my frameworks contain fat binaries). I found out that the frameworks in the visual studio project (path: ../ProjectName/ProjectName/obj/Debug) are smaller than the one that I imported and I am not able to see their package content also.

Comment: Are they are all **fat** frameworks at include arm64 and x86_64 binaries?

Comment: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/binding_objective-c/walkthrough/#Creating_a_Fat_Binary as Sushi said, check if you was creating
 a correct fat  Binary

Comment: Yes.. I'm using Fat binaries. All of them contains i386 x86_64 armv7 arm64.